# JSTree - on auto-refresh turns to plain ul li

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am generating JSTree from a MySQL table using PHP.  I have three files.

**index.php** - page where I have the div to load the JStree.

**autorefreshtree.php** - page that connects to mysql, fetch the data and echo the ul and li's.

**jtree.js** - this page holds the jquery function to convert the ul and li's to a tree with checkbox.

**Index.php**

```
<div class="rhsbar2"> <!-- JSTree begins -->       
   <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="annotateDirectories">

    </div> 
   </div>
</div> <!-- JSTree ends -->

<script>
function autoload() {
  xmlhttp =new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "autorefreshtree.php", false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  document.getElementById('annotateDirectories').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}

autoload();

//load every two seconds
setInterval(function(){
  autoload();
},2000);
</script>
```

**autorefreshtree.php**

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';
    if ($connect->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
    }
    category_tree(0);
    function category_tree($catid){
        global $connect;
        $sql = "select * from `tree` where `parentid` ='$catid'";
        $result = $connect->query($sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)):
            $i = 0;
            if ($i == 0) echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>' . $row->node_name;
                category_tree($row->tree_id);
                echo '</li>';
            $i++;
            if ($i > 0) echo '</ul>';
        endwhile;
        }
    mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

**jtree.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#annotateDirectories").jstree({
        "checkbox": {   
        'tie_selection' : false,        
        'two_state' : true 
    },
    'plugins': ['wholerow','search','checkbox', 'sort']
    });
});
```

The problem that I am facing is, when the page loads, the tree gets rendered properly.  However when the reload happens after two seconds, instead of tree I get only the ul and li displayed.

[image: Before autoload] [image: after autoload]

Comment: Try this `setInterval(function(){
  autoload();
  $('#annotateDirectories').jstree(true).refresh();
},2000);`

Comment: @ksoni  Thank you....Still returns the ul li only after 2 seconds.

Comment: Please try this`$('#annotateDirectories').jstree("refresh");` It is something to do with refresh.

Comment: @ksoni  Thank you again...but this one too didn't work...In fact i have tried many versions with refresh and redraw.

Comment: ok, :-( Can you try changing this `document.getElementById('annotateDirectories').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` to `$('#annotateDirectories').jstree(true).settings.core.data = xmlhttp.responseText`  OR `$('#annotateDirectories').jstree(true).settings.core.data="autorefreshtree.php"` AND still add the refresh line `$('#annotateDirectories').jstree(true).refresh();` after setting the data.

Comment: @ksoni Many thanks again...I tried both...neither worked...I think because I have all the libraries related to jstree in index.php along with javascript that loads jstree, this page dies after initial load...when the autoload kicks in, it doesnt have the rest of the libraries and hence just loads the ul and li's.... i may be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it working for myself. I will paste my code here. You can just create index.php and autorefreshtree.php like below and it test it on your machine. If it works all fine try to make necessary changes in your code to make it work.

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.5/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var requestUrl = '/autorefreshtree.php';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#annotateDirectories").jstree({
           'core' : {
                'data' : {
                  'url' : requestUrl,
                }
            },
            "checkbox": {   
                'tie_selection' : false,        
                'two_state' : true 
            },
            'plugins': ['wholerow','search','checkbox', 'sort']
        });
    });
    setInterval( function(){ 
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:requestUrl,
          datatype:"html",
          success:function(data) {
              $('#annotateDirectories').jstree(true).settings.core.data = data;
              $('#annotateDirectories').jstree(true).refresh();
          }
        });
    }, 2000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="annotateDirectories">
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

> autorefreshtree.php

```
<ul>
    <li>
       A.1 Heading
       <ul> 
           <li><a href="">A.1.1 Heading</a></li>
           <li><a href="">A.1.2 Heading</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="">A.1.2.1 Heading</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">A.1.2.2 Heading</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">A.1.2.3 Heading</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">A.1.2.4 Heading</a></li>
                </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       B.1 Heading
       <ul> 
           <li><a href="">B.1.1 Heading</a></li>
           <li><a href="">B.1.2 Heading</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="">B.1.2.1 Heading</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">B.1.2.2 Heading</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">B.1.2.3 Heading</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">B.1.2.4 Heading</a></li>
                </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent....thanks ton...this is something i was fighting over for a week now....many many thanks....I will integrate this into my code.

Comment: I have integrated this into my code...it is working...many thanks again.

Comment: @Apricot you are welcome! The refreshing logic was tricky, but I am glad it is working for you now :-)

Comment: sorry for being a pest...would it be possible to retain the checked status on refresh...i tried with `keep_selected_style=true` and other JS options to keep the check box checked on refresh....but doesn't work

Comment: I haven't done it myself but I believe there might be two ways which you can explore. Firstly, before you refresh the tree using ajax, you can try to get selected values and then after refresh update the tree with the previously selected values. This option might have issue when items change in your tree when new items start appearing. Other robust option might be whenever a item is selected send that to your database to store it temporarily and whenever you retrieve ul/li try those ones to be selected automatically.

Comment: thank you again....I will try the second option as it sound easier to me.  Thank you.